# CURL set date via php

Tags: php, date, curl, header

i have been searching around for awhile without any luck.
im wondering if it is possible to set the date of a server with curl()?

i currently got this code to login and retrive data

```
    $ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $loginURL); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6"); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookieFile); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookieFile); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $loginURL); 

curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
```

But sometimes i the server im getting data from, to think that it is another date.
i know i can mane another curl "partion" to get data from at specifik date by the url, but i figure it is faster to only call the remote server once, so if it is possible to set a header or something?

**I specific wonna do this: trick the server, that i call via CURL to think that it is to days in the future**

Comment: This isn't possible unless you have actual time traveling capabilities in your script. No server will be dumb enough to listen to the client's info about what time it is

Answer (score 0):

You should have a detailed look at the:

[PHP.net setopt Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php)

With curl, you can set a full header with curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header).
I don't entirely understand what you are attempting to in your specific case but hopefully this example might be useful:

```
    $agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.0; en-US)';
    $header[0] = "Accept: text/xml,application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,";
    $header[0] .= "text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*/*;q=0.5";
    $header[] = "Cache-Control: max-age=0";
    $header[] = "Connection: keep-alive";
    $header[] = "Keep-Alive: 300";
    $header[] = "Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7";
    $header[] = "Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5";
    $header[] = "Pragma: ";
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);//s[array_rand($agents)]);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 0);
    $fileContents = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
```

Further, if you are working with multiple curl requests you might consider a great library written by Josh Frasier, called [Rolling_Curl](http://code.google.com/p/rolling-curl/).

Comment: I will consider the library thanks. 
Okay lets say that i contact a server via CURL, i wonna trick this server to think that the date is 2 days from now

Comment: @MagnusJensen Lol, trick the server into thinking it is two days from now?  I hate to tell you this but the server has no problem telling time...

Comment: Okay, i thought there maybe was a way when you also could set the useragent